# Enter key presses button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How do I get the enter key to press a button (when pressed in a text box)?

This is my code:

```
     private void bar_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            bargo.Click;
        }
    }
```

'bar' is the name of the textbox.

'bargo' is the name of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the error you're getting in your question, but it looks like it's an issue with the `Click` call rather than the `Enter` button. Try this

```
private void bar_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        ButtonHandler_Click(bargo,null);
    }
}
```

where `ButtonHandler_Click` is your button's `Click` event handler.

Better yet would be to call a method that `ButtonHandler_Click` also calls, rather than doing all the logic in the `ButtonHandler_Click` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

There is another, simpler way to achieve this (depends on your situation though):
You can set the form's `AcceptButton` property to the button you want pressed, which usually is like "OK" or "Submit".